# jQuery UI Tabs selected index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to figure out how to solve an issue where I want to select the previously active tab. I have been playing around with cookies to store the tab index.

But now my problem is, how can I use the tab index to manipulate content in the specified tab index?

for example what can someone do when you retrieve the selected index?

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var jnode = $('#tabs').tabs("option", "panel");
```

jnode - jquery object for tab content.

**Update:**

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // => 0

$('#example').tabs("option", "panel").find('.ui-tabs-panel').eq(selected);
```

Comment: I don't understand what my result is here. Do I get the active tab object? What I want to get is the ID of the selected index.

Comment: I don't understand what the last line does... i have same problem. want to get selected index and remove..

Comment: It get panel option (which is jQuery object for the content of the panel) then find all tags that have .ui-tabs-panel class (it's the class that UI tabs add to element that have panel content) and then call eq which return element with selected index — if you want to remove selected just call remove() at the end.